# Get the exact string return by the Ok() in Asp.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

I have RESTful API that returns some large JSON files. I want to save the content to a file before sending it to the client. Here's my endpoint now:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("rest/result")]
public IActionResult GetResult(string requestId)
{
    var item = _service.GetItem(requestId);
    return item?.Result == null ? NotFound() : Ok(item.Result);
}
```

I tried this code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("rest/result")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetResult(string requestId)
{
    var item = _service.GetItem(requestId);
    var str = JsonSerializer.Serialize(item.Result);
    await File.WriteAllTextAsync($"c:\\output\\{requestId}.json", str);
    return item?.Result == null ? NotFound() : Ok(item.Result);
}
```

But the file is a bit different. Probably in terms of encoding because I'm seeing things such as : `"Data":"{\u0027FnId\u0027:\u002710000149\u0027` in the file.

Comment: What if you add a Produces attribute at the class level ? ie . [Produces("application/json")] ? same result? just curious because with that attribute you force all formatters.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator the class already has that attribute.

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't be any problem, as both representations are equivalent.

`\u0027` is Unicode for apostrophe ('). So, special characters are returned in Unicode but will show up properly when rendered on the page:

```
"Data":"{'FnId':'10000149'}"
```